# .htaccess cascading conditions

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to figure out how to manage potentially conflicting conditions in .htaccess

My setup is the following:
 - I have a CMS running on a server that can be accessed through myCMSdomain.com where myCMSdomain.com would be CMS home page and myCMSdomain.com/admin would be the admin interface.
 - Sites using this CMS should be pointing to myCMSdomain.com/sites/index.php
 - Images for all sites are available somewhere behind myCMSdomain.com/admin/images/sitename/...

So here is how I tried to tackle this problem:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www.)?myCMSdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . sites/index.php
```

With this, all incoming requests coming from other domain names are treated correctly by the index.php file but as images are hosted somewhere else, I'd like to use a rule saying that images should be fetched somewhere else like this:

Visible url format for images is: images-[sitename]/[image_path]
Real location of the images is: admin/site/[sitename]/[image_path]

The following rule works but not in combination with the first rule

RewriteRule images-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/(.*)$ admin/site/$1/images/$2

Images end up calling index.php instead of using the rule I defined for them.
I have tried to excluse the image directory from the conditions but it doesn't work either:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(images-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/(.*))
```

I might have similar issues in the future with other exception so I was wondering if there was a way to handle this.

Thanks!
Laurent

**UPDATE 1:**
If I use the following rule on top of all other

it works only if I'm using myCMSdomain.com domain name
if I use any other domain like anotherdomain.com, the rule leads to a http 500

```
RewriteRule images-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/(.*)$ manager/site/$1/images/$2
```

So http://www.myCMSdomain.com/images-test/test.jpg leads me to the correct image
But http://www.anotherdomain.com/images-test/test.jpg leads me to a 500 http error code while this domain is pointing correctly to sites/index.php

**UPDATE 2:**
On Justin's request, here is a view on the physical directory structure on the server

```
/admin/
/admin/site
/admin/site/site_name/
/admin/site/site_name/images/
/sites/
/sites/js
/sites/css
```

Comment: Where is your .htaccess located in this path? For what URL you get 500 and what exact URL do you use? Also check your Apache error.log for the reason of 500 error

Comment: htaccess file is in the root, one level higher than /admin/ or /sites. It's not a dedicated server, I can't access all logs but from what I can see, I have a recurring error: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: I also need to know if there is another .htaccess in any of the subdirectories under root?

Comment: no it's the only htaccess on this server. Thanks

Comment: You need to enable `RewriteLog` and add the rewrite log in question when your are getting 500.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rearrange your conditions logic.

```
# if www.myCMSdomain.com or myCMSdomain.com -> do nothing
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?myCMSdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# if we reach here, this means it's a subdomain/another domain

# images rule
RewriteRule ^images-([^/]+)/(.+)$ /admin/site/$1/images/$2 [L]

# not a file/directory -> sites/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /sites/index.php [L]
```

It is also possible the way you did but it would be longer to write.
Also, keep in mind that conditions (`RewriteCond`) are non-cumulative: they are for next rule (`RewriteRule`) **only**.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer Justin!

The image rule leads me to a http 500 error code. The rule works if I use the myCMSdomain.com domain but if I use another domain name pointing to the server, it leads me to a http 500 error. Any idea?

Comment: Could you give a clearer arborescence of your folders ? Because it was difficult to represent reading your question

Comment: Sure, just added the detail. It looks like external domains are not allowed to go back in the structure and take something from the admin directory

Comment: You have to make sure *mod_rewrite* is enabled and *htaccess* allowed in your Apache configuration. Then, make sure all your other domains are pointing to the same document root as myCMSdomain.com and put your htaccess in root folder. After that, this should work

Comment: mod_rewrite is enabled, rewriting works when rules are separated and htaccess is in the root directory.

Comment: Could you give me an example of non-working and working urls ? Same when you "separate" rules (by the way, what do you mean by "separate" ?)

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this issue for some time now but at last I think I have found the issue. It looks like there was something wrong in the domain name configuration, I don't know exactly what but once I had re-saved the mapping of all domains, the htaccess worked the way it should.

In the end I have used Justin's proposition, it looks more future proof than mine.

Thanks for your help and happy new year to all

Laurent